# How can I edit ul li font size and style?

Tags: html, css

I am now try to buliding my github blog with jekyll.

I want to change the target font style/size of "li" of ul in specific page.

I find that the target is in output html file

```
   <div class="content">
      <div class="container">
         <div class="post">
    <h3>Project</h3>
    <ul style="fontsize:3em">
        <li> **target**</li>
        <ul>
```

and the all css style manage from style.css file

below is only option on post class ol and ul

```
.post ol ol,
.post ol ul,
.post ul ol,
.post ul ul {
    margin: 0
}
```

- I want to declare new ul style with new name but I wanna inherit some ul properties.

then How can I do that?

in my think

```
.post ul ul2 {
    font-size : 2em 
}
```

but it does not work ...

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Fix that first. Only `<li>` elements may be children of a `<ul>`. Also, `fontsize` should be `font-size`. The markup you show is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I uploaded partiton of html file and It already work. and  "fontsize" is automatically maded output of jekyll decoder so I cannot handle of this. Maybe I need re-write the question with more information! thanks

Comment: Hi, maybe you should just write your html and css together and comment exactly what you want there or put it on codepen.

Answer (score 0):

Using child selector to select the inner ul

```
.post ul > ul{font-size:inherit}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! But my question is I wanna use 2 type of ul. the 1 is original ul(which already fixed by original theme from css.style the other one is cumtumized "ul2". Then .post ul > ul{font-size:inherit} is working ? as example, I wanna use